# Agregar el nombre del país correspondiente al que pertenece el año de independencia

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

vengo a pedir ayuda para encontrar alguna forma de lo que quiero obtener. Tengo un DataFrame llamado "country" que tiene unas cuantas columnas, dentro de ellas están: "Continent", "Name" (se refiere al nombre del país) y "IndepYear" (se refiere al año de independencia de cada país). Lo que quiero obtener es imprimir el primer país, de cada continente, que se independizó.

A continuación comparto lo que he obtenido, utilizo el método ".groupby" para que, de cada continente, me obtenga el año mínimo (ya que pide el primer país independizado) de independencia, sin embargo, quiero mostrar también el nombre del país correspondiente a cada año de independencia, pero no he encontrado alguna forma de realizarlo.

```
indep = country.groupby(['Continent'])[['IndepYear']].min()
indep
```

Esto ha sido lo que me imprime hasta el momento, lo que quiero es solo agregar los países que corresponden a cada año que se muestra en la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien sabe alguna otra forma que no sea con .groupby, igualmente la acepto, no tiene que ser forzosamente con ella

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

**Nota:** Siempre es importante agregar un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para que las respuestas reflejen el resultado que deseas utilizando tus datos. En este caso tuve que crear un ejemplo genérico que tendrás que adaptar a tus datos.

Lo puedes lograr fácilmente utilizando [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) en combinación con [`pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html)

Primero agrupas por tu columna de continentes, tal como lo haces. Lo único que te hace falta es "filtrar" el `dataframe` agrupado utilizando únicamente las filas donde la columna de independencia tenga el menor valor, para eso utilizamos [`pandas.DataFrame.idxmin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmin.html).

Ejemplo genérico:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['ca', 'cb', 'ca', 'cb', 'cb', 'ca'],
                   'B': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
                   'C': [1, 6, 3, 4, 5, 2]})

# Agrupar por la columna 'A', encontrar el valor mínimo de 'C' y agregar todas las columnas restantes
result = df.groupby('A').apply(lambda group: group.loc[group['C'].idxmin()])

print(result.reset_index(drop=True))
```

Esto imprime:

```
    A  B  C
0  ca  a  1
1  cb  d  4
```

Comment: Buenas noches. Perfecto, muchísimas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: No hay de que, saludos!